# Microsoft Word doc - converting a header to normal style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Microsoft Word document that is formatted as a heading 4 and as a numbering like so:

```
J2J-2    This a description and I want to convert this to normal.
J2J-3    This a description and I want to convert this to normal.
```

I need to have this number value "J2J-2,J2J-3" remain as a heading 4, but need the text description to become normal text and not part of the heading. It seems that word is treating this as one object and as a numbering.

As soon as I convert the numbering to normal using the styles pane, it will remove the "J2J-2, J2J-3".

```
This a description and I want to convert this to normal.
This a description and I want to convert this to normal.
```

I need to do this for many entries that are formatted like this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Automatically incremented by what?  It sounds like you're using a Word document that created/automated with something else.  If that true, then you probably don't want to (or can't) monkey with the document without also changing whatever's automating it.

Comment: Not being an familiar with word, I can see there is a numbering value of 1. This document does have a table of contents. Perhaps I can see if there is a mapping to this value.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're looking at, or with dummy data? That would make your question easier to undestand.

Comment: After stripping this document down further. The string as I described above is part of numbering. So my goal is to somehow convert the numbering to a normal paragraph, but to also keep the numbering scheme in place. So, i'm looking for number, followed by the text.

Comment: @digitxp - I cleaned up the question and example to hopefully explain the issue better. I don't have enough reputation to import an image. thanks for your help.